# Powershell memory management

Tags: powershell, memory-management

It is sure that PowerShell scripts will take some memory to run it.
But I don't know how the memory concepts work in the script.

If it is a programming language, We know the data types and memory allocation concepts.

So In PowerShell how it works?

Comment: What concepts are you talking about? Objects are allocated, use memory and are destroyed at some point so memory is freed? It's heavily reliant on .NET so most likely the same concepts apply.

Comment: @Seth  If I am executing scripts continuously without freeing? or What if I pipelined many scripts in c#?

Comment: Why in C#? It doesn't really look like you actually know what you're looking for? Obviously if you never free you will eventually eat up all the memory.

Comment: PowerShell is reasonably good at cleaning up after itself. Of course you can invoke the garbage collector manually, but that is rarely required. And as Seth pointed out, PowerShell is built on top of .Net, so basically the .Net memory management concepts apply.

Comment: PowerShell's based on .NET, meaning the same rules of garbage collection apply to it as to any other managed language. Typically, memory is not something you worry about in scripting languages until you notice that you're running out of it, and then you identify the specific problem and solve it.